# file-exists check for php's auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, apache2, vhosts

I currently have the situation that in my `vhost.conf` i have an entry to automatically include a file to start profiling:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/xhprof/include/xhprof.php
```

This thing is in SVN and might be checked out by people who don't have xhprof installed on their system. The consequence is, that `xhprof.php` is not found and PHP throws an error.

Does anybody know, if there's a possibility to check, if this file is there, before including?

thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

fileX.php:

`if(is_file("/home/xhprof/include/xhprof.php")){
include '/home/xhprof/include/xhprof.php';
}`

vhost.conf:

`php_value auto_prepend_file path/to/fileX.php`

there is a function called: [is_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

Comment: Thanks I already thought about a similar solution but this is not very useful, cause then you would have to add this file to all the projects that might use profiling.
What i just thought about is shell-similar entry like 
`<if exists [filename]>` for my vhost.conf, but i couldn't find anything like this yet